# Pycharm debug: is there a continue button?

Tags: pycharm

Just start using Pycharm on a **Django** project. In the debug area, I can see `step into`, `step over`, `step out`.. etc.. common debugging features just like any other IDE. However, I cannot see a `continue` button, which is for making the program run normally again. Where is it?

Comment: It's to the left of the debugger pane. It looks like an playbutton with stripes after it, the label should say "Resume program (F9)".